How to get pin locations detailed as zoomed in the map in SwiftUI
How can i get these pins detailed as shown in the pictures? For example i have an app showing listings for a particular purpose. Each listing holds a location as name(not longitude and latitude as of now) . I want to show a map showing the number of listings in a particular&larger area, then when the user zooms in I want to show listings in specific locations one by one. How to achieve this roughly?



I think there is more than one way to do this. Your first priority is to control the zoom, after the zoom level, the number and shapes of the annotations will change.

region.span.latitudeDelta
region.span.longitudeDelta

you can calculate the widths of the areas according to these zoom levels and continue your operations accordingly.

The problem is i am on Swiftui. Is it possible on Swiftui or uikit? This is called clustering no?

Even if you use SwiftUI, you can perform these operations by calling your view with UIViewRepresentable. You don't need to use SwiftUI Map.

SwiftUI Map does not support clustering, as of iOS 18 beta (and iOS 17). You'll have to fall back to MKMapView and wrap that for SwiftUI. Clustering in MKMapView works nicely.
